# react-navigation v6 lazy load specific tab only

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

So I really tried searching for the answer first before I asked it but there wasnt any good up to date answer.

Tech stack:
React-Native
React-Navigation v6
BottomTabBar

Question: I am trying to lazy load 3 tabs and eagerly load 2 other tabs. Any idea how I can do it the only option react-navigation v6 gives is a bool property which can set all views in the tab as lazy load or not. Anyone here know what the best way to approach this problem ?

I found some sources say to use a hook to focus your screens so that they force loading on them etc. however this was for version 1 and that hook doesnt exist anymore.

I did find a post about v4 and how they solved it but I think there should be a better solution with v6

Answer (score 3):

You can give the lazy option to specific screen using the `options` prop of Screen component.

```js
{/* lazy: true means that all of the screen's default load is lazy */}
<BottomTabStack.Navigator initialRouteName="ScreenName1" screenOptions={{lazy: true}}>
  <BottomTabStack.Screen
    name="ScreenName1"
    // Passing lazy: false will override the default lazy: true
    options={{lazy: false}}
    component={ScreenComponent1}
  />

  <BottomTabStack.Screen
    name="ScreenName2"
    // Passing lazy: true will override the default lazy: true, so no change
    options={{lazy: true}}
    component={ScreenComponent2}
  />

  <BottomTabStack.Screen
    name="ScreenName3"
    component={ScreenComponent3}
    // Not passing any lazy value will use the default lazy: true 
  />
</BottomTabStack.Navigator>
```

You can take a look at the documentation for more info: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options/#options-prop-on-screen

Comment: awesome thank you! was looking through docs but could not find it probably was looking in the wrong place. Will try it out.